# Android Support Library Cached?

Tags: android

I recently fixed a bug in my code related to the latest support lib, 25.1.0. However, there's something I want to ask in relation to debugging this issue. Take this into consideration. When I rollback to a previous version of my code, everything works as expected. Then, when I upgrade this old app version code to the latest support library, it breaks just as it does in my latest app code (as expected). Now, when I check out my latest app code again, and do the opposite, downgrade the support lib to 25.0.1, and run it, it's still broken. Does the system cache the support lib by default?

Comment: Have you synced your gradle files? Neglecting to do so would explain the last case

Comment: Yep, I'm forced to sync when a change to build.gradle is made. In this case, when rolling back the support lib to 25.0.1 to my latest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that one of your application dependencies **requires** the version of the support tools in question.  You can view the list of the dependencies on the command line using gradle(w) - typically:

```
./gradlew :<app>:dependencies --configuration <your configuration here>
```

where <your configuration here> is something like compileDebug, etc.

The graph will show you which versions of each dependency that you have explicitly called out, and the *transitive dependencies* of that library.

There is a chance that one of them is overriding your change to 25.0.1 because it requires 25.1.0 to work.  And, since the support library is considered to be 'backwards compatible', doesn't raise any red flags when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

All Maven/Gradle libraries are downloaded to disk once, if that's what you're asking. Nothing is cached between runs if you properly clean the project, and edit your compiled libraries